# Iterating over multiple parse.com classes (tables) and extracting queries

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform, callback, promise

Im betting this has something to do with asynchronicity of Javascript or something like that. I just read up about promises and thought it might solve my issue, but it hasnt yet. Anyhow, here is a code snippet and what Im aiming to achieve with it:

The scenario: I would like to query 10 tables and get the most recent posts(for sake of this example, 1 post) and store that in a dictionary of format

```
<Class Name> : <Obj Id>
```

The below code snippet does the following, or tries to do the following:

1. Build an array called activeTables, that contains the list of tables to query. This array itself is stored on a separate table called Config
2. For each item of the array activeTable, perform a query on that item, for the most recent item and add it to the dictionary

Seems straightforward but here's the result Im getting:

Assuming we run this on 3 tables called Table_1, Table_2, Table_3 and the most recent objs on each table are: recent_1, recent_2, recent_3 respectively, what I see on newlist is this:

```
newlist = {
   "Table_1" : ["recent_1", "recent_2", "recent_3"]
}
```

instead of :

```
newlist = {
    "Table_1" : ["recent_1"],
    "Table_2" : ["recent_2"],
    "Table_3" : ["recent_3"],
}
```

and it beats me, that while I was able to query the 3 tables and get the most recent post, only upon inserting it into the dictionary, it refuses to add a new key per table, once one key exists

(Also, am I using promises wrong? Since i still see the familiar pyramid of callback hell )

Code snippet referenced above:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("scanLists", function(request, status) {
  var activeTables = [];
  var getclass = Parse.Object.extend("Config");
  var query = new Parse.Query(getclass);
  query.equalTo("Name", "ActiveTablesConfigObj");
  query.find().then(function(activetables_obj) {
    var newlist = {};
    activeTables = activetables_obj[0].get("cObject").Active.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < activeTables.length; i++) {
      var t_name = activeTables[i];          
      var get_atc = Parse.Object.extend(t_name);
      var query_newlist = new Parse.Query(get_atc);
      query_newlist.descending("createdAt");
      query_newlist.find().then(function (newlist_obj) {
        if (newlist.t_name === undefined) {
          newlist[t_name] = [newlist_obj[0].id];
        } else {
          newlist[t_name].push(newlist_obj[0].id);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can improve the code in a few ways.  (1) Make smaller functions that return promises, (2) use query.first() instead of find() when we want only a single result.  To illustrate these two points, here's a function that returns a promise to get the first "Config" object:

```
function getConfig() {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Config");
  query.equalTo("Name", "ActiveTablesConfigObj");
  return query.first();
}
```

It looks like, later on in the code, you want to get the newest object of a given class.  Heres' a concise function for that:

```
function newestInstanceOf(klass) {
    var query = new Parse.Query(klass);
    query.descending("createdAt");
    return query.first();
}
```

Here's the tricky part (and the part that's most in need of fixing in your solution)... query.first() and .find() run asynchronously.  Your code contains a for-loop that generates several promises that complete only after the function has returned.  Not sure what your actual code looks like, but here's how to do it properly, collecting promises in an array, then executing them together with Promise.when():

```
_ = require("underscore");  // just a great util for arrays, providing things like map()

function scanLists() {
    var newlist = {};
    return getConfig().then(function(config) {
        var activeTables = config.get("cObject").Active;
        // build an array of promises to get the most recent object in each class
        var promises = _.map(activeTables, function(klass) {
            return newestInstanceOf(klass).then(function(newestInstance) {
                if (!newlist[klass]) { newlist[klass] = []; }
                newlist[klass].push(newestInstance.id);
            });
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
   }).then(function() {
       return newlist;
   });
}
```

Notice how everything returns a promise?  Last thing...call this from a cloud function, including calling response success/error:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("scanLists", function(request, response) {
    scanLists().then(function(newlist) {
        // do something with newlist, if this involves a promise, then...
        return someObject.save();
    }).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Really enjoyed reading this danh! Fantastic summary and suggestions - and a lot to take away for me and improve the code quality

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The answer is I must use anonymous functions!

So the below code fixes the issue

```
Parse.Cloud.job("scanLists", function(request, status) {
  var activeTables = [];
  var getclass = Parse.Object.extend("Config");
  var query = new Parse.Query(getclass);
  query.equalTo("Name", "ActiveTablesConfigObj");
  query.find().then(function(activetables_obj) {
    var newlist = {};
    activeTables = activetables_obj[0].get("cObject").Active.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < activeTables.length; i++) {
      (function(i) {
        var t_name = activeTables[i];          
        var get_atc = Parse.Object.extend(t_name);
        var query_newlist = new Parse.Query(get_atc);
        query_newlist.descending("createdAt");
        query_newlist.find().then(function (newlist_obj) {
          if (newlist.t_name === undefined) {
            newlist[t_name] = [newlist_obj[0].id];
          } else {
            newlist[t_name].push(newlist_obj[0].id);
          }
        });
      })(i);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Glad you have this working, but I don't see how it can be.  The code returns without actually building `newlist` (due to not handling promises from the find() in the for loop). Also, it must call success() or error() on the status parameter (customarily named "response").  How do you collect evidence that it worked?

Comment: Hi @danh, here's what Im seeing, with respect to newlist, but please let me know if something is glaringly wrong, as I am still new to JS and Parse: newlist is delcared before the for loop. It is then accessed inside the for loop as keys are created if they dont exist, or a value is pushed to the array that the key pertains to. Im my actual code, when i exit the for loop, newlist is a full dictionary with the expected key, value pair, which I then write to a different object back on parse

Comment: Okay.  Maybe the reason its working better than it appears is something in the "actual code".  I'll write up a couple thoughts real quick, just to clear up a few items in what you've posted.